# Is it legal to put someone’s mail in their mailbox?

Tags: united-states, postal-service

If you printed up a flier and walked around shoving them into people’s mailboxes, that would be illegal because it is misuse of postal systems/property.

But what if someone else’s mail gets delivered to you by mistake? Can you just put it in their mailbox? Can anyone just use mailboxes as long as they are being used rightfully and lawfully, or do you have to be some sort of “Certified Deputy of the Postmaster General”?

I know you can just write “delivered to wrong address” on the envelope, but sometimes it is easier to just bring it a few doors down.

Assume for the sake of the question that the mailbox is on or near a public road (accessible without trespassing).

Comment: That's what posties do. What makes you think only they can do it?

Comment: I believe that the answer is yes, it is O.K., but I haven't verified it.

Comment: I don’t know anyone who has ever worked for the post office. I didn’t know if they had some sort of badge or certification process. There are certainly other types of public servants (like police) that are granted permissions not granted to everyone.

Comment: You have to visit that someone whose mail ended up in your possession and as **"May I have your permission/consent to touch your mailbox?"** If the answer is YES, you go and put the mail in... otherwise, just put it in someone else's (not someone's) mailbox and it's not longer your problem. - *This is by far the most ridiculous question I've ever seen. If someone would sue you for returning lost mail back to them, leave country pronto! You're in the wrong place at the wrong time.* - PS: Where I leave returning lost mail is called common curtesy and decency, and always appreciated.

Comment: In the US, you can legally print up flyers and shove them in people's mailboxes - as long as you pay the postage.

Comment: *If you printed up a flier and walked around shoving them into people’s mailboxes, that would be illegal because it is misuse of postal systems/property.* As a French getting tons of ads from my mailbox despite the official "no ads" sticker, having such a law is wonderful.

Comment: @CodeAngry What you're missing is that it's a Federal crime in the United States to put things (e.g. fliers) in a mailbox directly. The illegality here is not against the owner of the mailbox, but against the United States itself (who has quasi-ownership right to the space inside the mailbox). "I had the recipient's permission" doesn't factor into it, because it's not the owner of the land the mailbox is on which counts, but the "owner" of the space inside the mailbox.

Comment: I understand that it is fairly unlikely that anyone would actually get in trouble over this, but (1) the point of this SE is to understand laws, (2) even if the chance of being punished is low, it isn’t zero, and (3) some people actually just like to do the right thing even if there is no real threat of punishment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The specific reason why you can't deliver general fliers in mailboxes is [18 USC 1725](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1725), which says

> Whoever knowingly and willfully deposits any mailable matter such as
> statements of accounts, circulars, sale bills, or other like matter,
> on which no postage has been paid, in any letter box established,
> approved, or accepted by the Postal Service for the receipt or
> delivery of mail matter on any mail route with intent to avoid payment
> of lawful postage thereon, shall for each such offense be fined under
> this title.

Misdirected mail has the requisite postage, therefore you can put it in the mailbox.

Comment: There seems to be an important fact missing from the hypothetical.  If the letter was addressed to another mailbox and delivered to OP's box, then in that case it would seem clearly legal to place it in the correct box.  However, if it was OP's address on the envelope even though it was supposed to be addressed to another one, USPS could make the argument that delivering it somewhere else requires postage to use the mailbox, since from their perspective there was no mistake and rerouting is a new delivery.

Comment: So, it's legal to put your junk mail into other people's post boxes, as long as you pay the post office for the right to do so first?

Comment: @nick012000 you can even pay them to put that junk for you.

Comment: I'm really puzzled that the USPS (and federal government) is interested in the mailbox at someones house. And that they name it a "established, approved, or accepted" letter box. Is there a procedure for approving a letter box by the USPS? Here in Germany my leter box is my property and the state has no interest who uses it to communicate with me. With unwanted fliers you can deal via private law directly against the distributor, if it is a bigger harassment.

Comment: There is a procedure, but it's between USPS and the manufacturer so I don't know what the actual approval process is. It does functionally preclude carving your own mailbox.

Comment: @K-HB yes, there are standards. And the reason why they care has something to do with the "Universal Service Obligation" — USPS is required to deliver to everyone in the country, within a certain timeframe, at a flat rate, no matter how remote or inconvenient the location. In return they get a certain monopoly status, so that they don't get stuck with *only* the most inconvenient destinations (as someone without the universal obligation could deliver more cheaply to most locations).

Comment: @hobbs They don’t need a monopoly for that, just a law requiring would-be competitors to also provide a universal flat-rate service, and to not remail without consent.

Comment: @MikeScott I'm simplifying. It's not a pure monopoly. But in any case how it works is how it works, regardless of if it's the *best*.

Comment: And the people who deliver fliers and handbills aren't really deterred, at least if they aren't delivering to apartments; they just leave it somewhere else on the property besides the mailbox (it's not uncommon for them to have a rubber band attached, so they can be hooked on door handles). Which is arguably worse, since it's easier for them to blow away and create litter, easier to miss that they're there, and they can pile up and tell others you may be away from home since they're in plain view instead of inside a mailbox.

Comment: @K-HB: we do have in the EU a EU approved mailbox (I cannot find the link right now but it was decided years ago to accommodate pick-up by the post offices directly from the mailboxes, and also delivery of packages there). Thi is not an obligation, though, just something everyone agreed upon. I live in a flat and we have a completely non-standard mailbox which thank god is wide enough for an envelope with A4 pages (and Amazon sometimes manages to squeeze their package too)

Comment: @K-HB I'm also somewhat surprised (as a fellow German); but it is worth mentioning that in the U.S. you can use your private mailbox to *send* letters as well: ["Letter carriers can pick up mail as they make their deliveries if the flag is up."](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/Outgoing-Mail-Pickup). Private mail boxes have a "flag" indicating that there is mail in there, in both directions, incoming and outgoing, to the customer and the postman alike. So a private mailbox serves as a drop-box as well and is a more integrated and hence regulated part of the postal service.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, under US law (18 USC 1725) you may place misdirected mail in the mailbox of the person to whom it is addressed. You may also just knock on that person's door and hand it to the addressee.

Comment: ...unless you follow the Covid distance orders, then you need to leave it on the porch and step back.

Comment: do you have a source for that?

Comment: @JCRM OP just consulted Common Sense Law.

Comment: If the answer says "under US law", it would be good to quote or reference the specific law involved.